# Createspace package with XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, incompatibility

I'm getting this compilation error from the [`createspace`](https://github.com/aginiewicz/createspace)package

`\PackageError{createspace}{no PDF supported engine detected}{recompile this document using PDFLaTeX}`

I'm using TeXShop typesetting with XeLaTeX with pdfTeX option. Is there a conflict between createspace and XeLaTeX?

Comment: The package uses `\immediate\pdfobj`, so it's not usable with XeLaTeX. Try LuaLaTeX, but I'm not sure it will do.